# Right way of getting specific columns in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In our app few of our Eloquent models need only a specific columns always. What is the right way to have my method? As of now there is a new method written which does,

`DB::table('MyTable')->selectRaw('required_column_list')`

I feel it is odd since the table name is hard-coded. What is the right way to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hard-code table name, so you have to hard code ModelName?
Use model name with getTable function
    
    `DB::table(YourModel::create()->getTable());`

Comment: this answers my question partially. But is this the right way to do when I need only specific columns to be selected?

Comment: How about `lists()` function? If you really need column only, I think it is enough.